# H2O GLM for heavy-tailed data

Tags: generalized-linear-model, heavy-tailed, h2o

I am trying to run H2O GLM (OLS, lasso, ridge, EN) for stock returns, which have very heavy tails (i.e. potentially infinite variance). Is there a robust loss function modification for this, say Huber or MAE?

Answer (score 2):

Infinite variances do not fit into GLM theory. I can see three options **within h2o**:

1. **glm**: Use a quite skewed distribution, e.g. a Tweedie with power >= 2. Tweedie power 3 is the inverse Gaussian.
2. **deeplearning**: Use the deep learning algo with robust loss function and without a hidden layer.
3. **xgboost**: Use xgboost with `booster = gblinear` and a robust loss function.